Jenkins JcasC for SonarQube Scanner
I implemented sonarqube with Jenkins JcacS
my sonarqube server implemented successfully but I can't find any documents to implement sonar scanner MSBuild in JcasC.

this one works for Sonar Scanner

      config-plugins: |-
        tool:
          sonarRunnerInstallation:
            installations:
            - name: "sonar-scanner"
              properties:
              - installSource:
                  installers:
                  - sonarRunnerInstaller:
                      id: "6.2.0.4584"

Can anyone help me how to implement Sonar Scanner MS.Build?


I found it in Jenkins log error. it suggested valid values
JCasC:
  config-plugins: |-
    tool:
      git:
        installations:
        - home: "git"
          name: "Default"
      sonarRunnerInstallation:
        installations:
        - name: "sonar-scanner"
          properties:
          - installSource:
              installers:
              - sonarRunnerInstaller:
                  id: "6.2.0.4584"
      msBuildSQRunnerInstallation:
        installations:
        - name: "sonar-scanner-msbuild"
          properties:
          - installSource:
              installers:
              - msBuildSonarQubeRunnerInstaller:
                  id: "5.15.0.80890-netcore3"

